# Issue with my CSS that I can't seem to figure out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to figure this one out. My web page at http://rayku.com/start has a text box that will expand a form below it when someone starts to type in it:

[expanded form http://snpr.cm/iurnmx.jpg](http://snpr.cm/iurnmx.jpg)

How it should work is that if you de-select from the text box without typing anything, it would go back to its original state. However, it seems to be working too well that if I click anything on the form itself below it, it would return to its original state.

How do I change it so that it will only go back to its original state if I don't type anything in the text box and I don't click anywhere on the form below it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the value of the field before allowing a 'close' animation. Something like this:

```
//store object in var for efficiency
var mainQuestion = $('.main-question input');
var initialValue = mainQuestion.val();

mainQuestion.focus(function(){
    //blank out field on focus
    if(mainQuestion.val() == initialValue){
        mainQuestion.val('');
    }
    //animate opening here
});

mainQuestion.blur(function(){
    //check to see if user has typed anything in
    if((mainQuestion.val() == initialValue) || !mainQuestion.val().length ){
        //reset value
        mainQuestion.val(initialValue);
        //animate closing here
    }
});
```

Comment: I noticed you use inline js on the form element to clear out the initial text and reset it. Don't do that, or any js inside of html, its bad karma.

Comment: Thanks! I've made the change and it seems to work great! Though now if I type something in the text field, select something else, then click the text field again, the text that I've typed disappears. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: I but the part that blanks out the field on focus, with in an if statement that checks the current value of that field. If the field has not yet been edited it will blank, otherwise it will not.